# Changing Authentication Method in Play IsAuthenticated

Tags: scala, playframework

I'd like to create a custom authentication method for a Play2 Framework app.
I'm trying it in Scala and Play -- and I'm new to both.

In the zentask example there is there is a function called IsAuthenticated in the Trait Secured:

```
  def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
Action(request => f(user)(request))
  }
```

This definition is fairly complex.  I've found a number of questions regarding the syntax of this definition on stackoverflow, but I'm still not sure how to change this.

I can see an authentication check happening in User.authenticate via a database lookup.  But the authentication that I want to do doesn't use a database.  I'm not sure how or where to wire in a different type of authentication.  Is Security.Authenticated() wired into using the User class/object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Security.Authenticated` just checks if session contains "username" key. If it does, user supposed to be authenticated.

You should authenticate your users yourself, by doing database lookup, or any other way. Then, store user id(or email, or just name) in the session:

```
val user = // fetch user info
Redirect("/").withSession("userId" → user.id.toString)
```

Then wrap actions in `Security.Authenticated` call:

```
def someAction = Security.Authenticated(
  req => req.session.get("userId"),
  _ => Redirect(views.html.login())) { userId =>
    Action {
      Ok(html.index())
    }
}
```

The first argument to `Authenticated` is a function that retrieves user id from the session. It returns an `Option[String]`, i.e. `Some[String]` if there is id in the session or `None` if there isn't.

```
req => req.session.get("userId")
```

The second argument is a function that returns `Result` to use, if session isn't contains user id. You will typically want a redirect to a login page.

```
_ => Redirect(views.html.login())
```

The final argument is a function returning `Action`. It is used if user is authenticated.

```
userId => Action {
  Ok(html.index())
}
```

You are not forced to use play implementation, feel free to wrap it in handy helper, or write it from scratch to fit your needs:

```
def myAuth(f: String => Result) = Security.Authenticated(
  req => req.session.get("userId"),
  _ => Redirect(views.html.login())) { userId =>
  Action {
    f(userId)
  }
}

def someAction = myAuth { userId =>
  Ok(html.index())
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  You've made it clearer for me.  I find this particular use of Scala a bit Perl-like in terms of readability.